# php excel download a file

Tags: php, excel, yii, download

Developers
I am using Yii1 and I want to generate a report using PHPExcel extension but my file is not ready to download, instead it appears in console. I also set headers but still file is not ready for download. I can't find exact answer. please resolve my problem

```
public function GenerateReport($dataProvider)
{

    $phpExcelPath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.phpexcel.Classes');
    include($phpExcelPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'PHPExcel.php');

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $fileName = 'report-'.uniqid().'.xlsx';
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Palash Gupta");
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle($fileName);
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("Placement Student List");
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("Placement Student List");
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $rowCount = 1;
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A' . $rowCount, 'Name');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B' . $rowCount, 'Course');

    $rowCount = 2;
    foreach ($dataProvider->getData() as $data)
    {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A' . $rowCount, $data['sd_fname']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B' . $rowCount, $data['fk_mc_id']);
        $rowCount++;
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$fileName.'"');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

[image]    }

Comment: The screenshot starts with the characters `PK`. That means we are looking on compressed (zipped) data.

Comment: It looks also like an .xlsx file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'. $fileName .'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Ref: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/01simple-download-xls.php

Comment: Sir! Still I'm unable to download the file